# Showing and Hiding content using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I am practicing JavaScript on my personal page and I am having trouble with the #fourth-page (Portfolio). Basically what I want is, when I click on Web Design, it shows the things under class="tab1-content", if I click on Games, it shows pics related to that div (under class="tab3-content) if that makes sense. I attached a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/donatkap/ynL4sf8e/) (some pics are missing cause idk how to upload pics.

My logic is pretty long so a better one would be appreciated too.

Here's my logic:

notice that I have an ID called "current-tab" which turns the selected tab green. 
Basically on every click, I remove that ID from every tab element, I also remove every tab content by setting the displays of tab1-content tab2-content tab3-content and tab4-content to none. Then I put the ID where it should be. However I can't figure out how to display the correct tab content I need. Please help?

I'm sure there's a better way to do this

```js
var tab1 = document.querySelector("#homepage #fourth-page .portfolio-container .tab1");
var tab2 = document.querySelector("#homepage #fourth-page .portfolio-container .tab2");
var tab3 = document.querySelector("#homepage #fourth-page .portfolio-container .tab3");
var tab4 = document.querySelector("#homepage #fourth-page .portfolio-container .tab4");
var tabs = document.querySelector("#homepage #fourth-page .portfolio-container .tabs");
var tabLinks = tabs.getElementsByTagName("a"); // Array
var temp = document.querySelector("#homepage #fourth-page .portfolio .tab-content-wrap");
var tabContents = temp.getElementsByClassName("tab-content");

// Initially, Web Design is green

console.log("testing");

tab1.setAttribute("id", "current-tab");

// If I click one, hide the other ones

//  Adding individual listening events
tab1.addEventListener("click", showContent);
tab2.addEventListener("click", showContent);
tab3.addEventListener("click", showContent);
tab4.addEventListener("click", showContent);

function showContent() {
  console.log("executing function");
  // give it #current tab, remove previous
  // display its content, remove other one

  for (let i = tabLinks.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    tabLinks[i].removeAttribute("id");
    tabContents[i].style.cssText = "display: none";
  }
  this.setAttribute("id", "current-tab");
}
```

Comment: Could you post your html along with this. It would be easier to understand what exactly you need.

Comment: If you want to link one group of elements to another group maybe you could use a `class` with an `id` to relate the class with the `id` to bind the elements together... this would mean one function to work with/for all. If you can include the `HTML` to go with this I might be able to give you an example.

Comment: Also you haven't assigned the element `ID` to the anchor tag `#contact-page` and you appear to be missing a `<section>` tag for `fifth-page` Here is a [**Working JsFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/0r95s3Lx/)

Comment: Your biggest problem is having two class attributes for your html tags. That is NOT the syntax. The syntax is to separate the classes by spaces: `class="one two"` and NOT `class="one" class="two"`

Comment: @NewToJS hey, that JSFiddle is the one I attached on my question so it doesn't work. Also Suhas, there's a link to the JS Fiddle in my question. And thank you for the observation about my syntax.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in a number of ways depending on your need.

The easiest and simplest is by far using Bootstrap Tabs which you can see in the link below:
https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_tabs_pills.asp

If you are wanting to code this yourself however I can make a recommendation

**Use Classes instead of IDs** - it is far easier to add and remove classes from elements than it is to change IDs (see example... its crude but it works and should point you down the right path)

```js
function viewMagicBox(boxRef) {
  var items = document.getElementsByClassName("magic-box active");
  var itemCount = items.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < itemCount; i++) {
    items[i].classList.remove("active");
  }
  document.getElementById(boxRef + "-content").classList.add("active");
}
```

```css
.active {
  display: block !important;
}

.magic-box {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<a onclick="viewMagicBox('box1')">Box1</a>&nbsp;<a onclick="viewMagicBox('box2')">Box2</a>&nbsp;<a onclick="viewMagicBox('box3')">Box3</a>&nbsp;<a onclick="viewMagicBox('box4')">Box4</a>
<div id="box1-content" class="magic-box">This is what is displayed in <span style="color:red;">Box 1</span></div>
<div id="box2-content" class="magic-box">This is what is displayed in <span style="color:blue;">Box 2</span></div>
<div id="box3-content" class="magic-box">This is what is displayed in <span style="color:green;">Box 3</span></div>
<div id="box4-content" class="magic-box">This is what is displayed in <span style="color:gold;">Box 4</span></div>
```

**Custom CSS Without Javascript** - There is also another little known option of using the `radio button` this is particularly handy if trying to display tabbed content in a site that does not allow active scripts.

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

li {
  padding: 10px;
  float: left;
}

input {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}

label {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.tabheader {
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: #394620;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  color: white;
}

.tab-content {
  display: none;
  background-color: white;
}

.tabheader:hover {
  background-color: grey;
  border: #394620 4px solid;
  color: #394620;
  margin-bottom: -4;
}

input:checked~.tab-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div role="tabpanel">
  <!-- Nav tabs -->

  <ul role="tablist">
    <li role="presentation"><label class="tabheader" for="magicTab1">Magic Tab 1</label></li>

    <li role="presentation"><label class="tabheader" for="magicTab2">Magic Tab 2</label></li>

    <li role="presentation"><label class="tabheader" for="magicTab3">Magic Tab 3</label></li>

    <li role="presentation"><label class="tabheader" for="magicTab4">Magic Tab 4</label></li>
  </ul>
  <!-- TAB START -->
  <div>
    <input type="radio" id="magicTab1" checked name="my_tabs">
    <div class="tab-content">
      <div class="tab-pane active" role="tabpanel">
        <h2>Tab 1 is the First</h2>
        <p>This is the first tab content</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="radio" id="magicTab2" name="my_tabs">
    <div class="tab-content">
      <div class="tab-pane active" role="tabpanel">
        <h2>Tab 2 is the Second</h2>
        <p>This is the second tab content</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="radio" id="magicTab3" name="my_tabs">
    <div class="tab-content">
      <div class="tab-pane active" role="tabpanel">
        <h2>Tab 3 is the Third</h2>
        <p>This is the third tab content</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="radio" id="magicTab4" name="my_tabs">
    <div class="tab-content">
      <div class="tab-pane active" role="tabpanel">
        <h2>Tab 4 is the Fourth</h2>
        <p>This is the fourth tab content</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- TABS END --->
</div>
```

Once again there are many other ways this hopefully has been helpful for you.